# Wordpress functionality plugin how to require file elsewhere on server?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

I need to require_once() a file in my Wordpress functionality plugin which resides at home/me/vendor/ on the server. Wordpress of course is in www/html.

Can someone direct me on how to define the path to the required file? Nothing I try seems to work.

```
<?php
echo "file runs";
// This file is generated by Composer
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
echo “file runs”;
$client   = new QuickEmailVerification\Client('api key');
$quickemailverification  = $client->quickemailverification();

try {
$response = $quickemailverification->verify("don2@inklines.art");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Code: " . $e->getCode() . " Message: " . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($response); 
echo "/<pre>"; 

?>
```

The first echo displays as expected (just a test).
The second one does not so, for starters, I think the file can’t locate the required() file.

I just need direction on getting the file found. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the absolute path for the vendor directory. Which would be /home/me/vendor. You should also ensure that Wordpress has permissions to access the directory.

Comment: BINGO! Thanks Andrew. Is there a way to accomplish that in a way other than hard coding the path?

Comment: Not really. The home directory is specific to each user. If the Wordpress application is running as the same user you could just use ~/vendor. However I don’t expect it will be. You’d be better off moving the vendor directory to another location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew. I ended up putting the include path in php.ini. All that’s required in the php file then is a reference to the file name.